# 'jQuery' is not defined error - Not Identified

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

_Layout.cshtml contains:

In Header

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

In Footer

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") 
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

In View Code added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
</script>
```

And no alert message displayed. There is something wrong with the script calling ?

Comment: please make sure your jquery library is loaded or not in the correct path?

Comment: you could set top position `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

Comment: verify the scripts folder has jquery scripts

Comment: Have put "~/bundles/jquery" in header section and it works. Thanks @pridemkA

Answer (score 2):

Well, try:

In Header

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

In Footer

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") 
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error usually happens when you try to use jQuery before it is included in the page.

Make sure your javascript code in the view is under the `scripts` section

```
@section scripts
{
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
   </script>
}
```

Assuming you have a `RenderSection` method call for this section in your layout **after** loading jQuery library

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

When razor executes the page, it replaces the scripts `RenderSection` call with the javascript code defined in the `scripts` section of the view.

Answer (score 1):

Verify your code under the jQuery scripts. Or move the scripts to the header section.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Your code should be below the jQuery scripts.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

check your bundleconfig.cs if it contains the following..

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

make sure your jquery is in the Scripts folder.

try to use jquery in the header at first place.